# Which topology is assumed here?

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing a problem from a previous exam in topology, but I'm uncertain which topology is given to this set. Here's the problem:

Let $Y = I^2\backslash\{(x,y) \in I^2 : x = \frac{1}{2}, y > \frac{1}{2}\}$ and equip it with its subspace topology $T_Y$ with respect to $(I^2, T_{I^2})$ What is $T_{I^2}$ in this case?

Comment: _Probably_ it's the subspace topology induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So all open rectangles $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in (0,1)$ including the entire "box" $[0,1]\times [0,1]$? $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ obv.

Comment: And rectangles like $[0,b) \times (c,d)$, $(0,1)\times (c,1]$ etc., and, more importantly, arbitrary unions of such rectangles.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right. Ok thank you. I'll assume you are right and see if I can solve it. Btw, when I encounter such "ambiguity", is there some kind of rule as to which topology is probably assumed, or is your guess mostly rooted in experience with topology?

Comment: For subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, unless specified otherwise, one assumes that the subspace topology induced by the standard topology is used. It's called the standard topology not without reason.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel: it’s almost certainly the relative topology from $\Bbb R^2$ with the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point. Thank you :)